# Spring JPA Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have some confusion about the Hibernate Spring and JPA.

See I am using Spring 3 & hibernate application and want to use JPA.

1) Can somebody help me in understanding of architecure and flow of Spring JPA and Hibernate
1) How can I use JPA in between them.
2) What would be the advantages of using JPA.
3) I read somewhere that if I use JPA then I can change my ORM framework easily. How can I change that ?

Could anybody please help me out from this confusion ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Architecture and flow of Spring JPA and Hibernate

The process for utilizing JPA in your Spring application is exceedingly simple:

- Include Spring-Data-JPA as a dependency
- Include a JPA provider (like hibernate jpa)
- Define your entities using `javax.persistence` annotations (such as `@Entity`, `@Id`, `@Table`, `@Column`, `@OneToMany`, etc)
- Create an interface for a repository for each entity (example below)
- Enable JPA repositories with `@EnableJPARepositories` annotation on a config

EXAMPLE:

```
PersonEntity.java

@Entity
class PersonEntity {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private Long id;

  @Column('name')
  private String name;

  public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
  public Long getId() { return this.id; }

  public void setName(String name) { this.name = name; }
  public String getName() { return this.name; }
}

PersonRepository.java

@Repository
Interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<PersonEntity, Long> {
//no really, that's all it takes. Spring will automatically create the repo
}
```

Then in your configuration, you'll need to define an `EntityManagerFactoryBean` as well as a `DataSource` bean.

Under the hood, Spring will magic you up a bunch of hibernate code that you interact with through the JPA repositories by `@Autowire`ing them into your controllers or services.

#### 2 & 3. Advantages of JPA

Since JPA is only a SPECIFICATION for accessing and persisting data, it is implementation agnostic. That means you can use any backend that implements JPA's functionality (Hibernate is just one common example) without having to change ANY of your code, since your code is only aware of the JPA spec.

It's a nice abstraction layer between your business logic, the ORM, and the database.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks so much it really helped me , So basically when we extending JpaRepository & proving some configuration in applicationcontext.xml internally it is handling the performing CRUD operation  through hibernate.

Comment: @ashishl That's exactly it. I'd recommend checking out the docs on http://spring.io They have some extensive examples, only part that tends to be lacking is the configurations since most of their samples utilize Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2):

**1) Can somebody help me in understanding of architecture and flow of Spring JPA and Hibernate**
**Answer)**  **JPA** -  JPA is a standardized API for database access from Java. By standardized I mean that its designers have taken into consideration the various ORM frameworks being used now-a-days and then defined an API which kind of covers the maximum-possible features of them all. Having said that, JPA API is a little tilted/influenced by hibernate as this was the most dominant and widely-used ORM framework (and still is).

**Spring-JPA** - Spring JPA or, Spring-Data-JPA as it is more popularly known as , is a module in Spring which provides JPA functionality to Spring users in a way which is very well integrated with Spring. I.e. anyone working in a Spring project just need to do a few settings and they can start using JPA if they use Spring Data JPA.

**Spring-JPA with hibernate** - JPA is ORM-agnostic. In other words, JPA can work with any ORM provider in Java provided there is an *adapter* existing which converts or *adapts* all JPA calls to the target ORM. This adapter goes by the term JPAVendorAdapter. You don't need to do much to use Hibernate with JPA. Just specify JPAVendorAdapter of type hibernate and have the necessary adapter jars in your classpath.
**Overall architecture or design flow** - While using JPA you use JPQL(Java Persistence Query Language) or JPA Criteria Query to define your database queries. JPA then delegates the DB connection handling and query execution to the *vendor* ORM through the JPAVendorAdapter.

**2) What would be the advantages of using JPA.**
**Answer)** JPA has its own syntax for querying the database such as JPQL or Criteria query etc. This JPA *query syntax* does not change, even when the underlying ORM is changed from say Hibernate to iBatis. What changes on changing the underlying ORM is just the JPAVendorAdapter setting and the relevant jars need to be placed accordingly.
Biggest advantage which JPA offers you is that ability to change the ORM provider with no/minimal change of code(why I say minimal is that some people debate about actual portability of JPA across ORM providers - but I believe this aspect is pretty stable and mature now and need not be worried about).

**3)I read somewhere that if I use JPA then I can change my ORM framework easily. How can I change that ?**
**Answer)** Already answered this one in my answer to question 2 above i.e. by changing the JPAVendorAdapter settings and placing the relevant jars in the classpath.